# Use VS Code on Mac to compile and run simulator Swift iOS projects

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-simulator, visual-studio-code

I'm basically trying to switch from Xcode to VS Code for iOS development in Swift.

**Is it possible to run the iPhone simulator when you build your project in VS Code, like it does in Xcode?** I've seen other questions where the answer has been no, but I'm wondering if there are any new workarounds or added features since then.

**Is it possible to view Storyboards somehow, or are there other programs you can use for that? I'm really tired of Xcode.**

Comment: As for the Storyboards I wouldn't expect any decent level of support from third parties - too complex and XCode IB with all it's crap is still too usable.

Comment: Regarding running simulator I'd imagine there should be a way - however getting into all the plumbing to make it consistently work (also after any updates by Apple might not be worth the effort).

Comment: In Visual Studio for Mac, on my Mac, I was able to create an iOS project and run it on a iOS simulator.

Comment: @pdschuller, details?!?!